# media queries are contradicting each other

Tags: css, media-queries

Hey friends I'm writing the media query for the footer of my website. I'm starting on a max-width of 425px. The first thing that gets messed up when i shrink the screen to this size is shown here -[image: Pic] The red line doesn't add up, so i adjust and fix it, but when i shrink the screen to a max-width of 375px the red line moves again, so I create another media query with a max-width of 375px and adjust the line and fix it at 375, but now when i move the screen back up to 425 that line moves again? completely ignoring that style. So i have to adjust it again. But this then messes it up at 375??? What's happening? It's back and forth plz help  -Example below

1st thing I do when I resize the screen to 425px and see the problem(as shown in the picture

```
`@media screen and (max-width: 425px) {
    .social .inner:after {
        margin-top: -40px;
  }
}`
```

The above code aligns the red line where it needs to be when the screen has a max width of 425px. However when I shrink the screen to 375px the line moves again so maybe I do something like this

```
`@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
   .social .inner:after {
       margin-top: -38px;
   }
}`
```

This fixes at 375px. What now happens though is when i go back to 425px the line moves again? and then if that wasn't enough if you shrink down to 375px its misaligned??? Try it out and see

```css
html, body {
 margin: 0; 
 padding: 0;
}

/*---HEADER---*/

header {
 background-image: url(../img/contact.jpg);
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
 background-size: cover;
 width: 100%;
 height: 65vh;
}

.contact-wrapper{
 width: 100%;
 height: 65vh;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

header h1 {
 color: white;
 font-size: 5rem;
 font-family: 'Arvo';
 margin: 0;
}

/*---NAV---*/

nav {
 background-color: white;
 width: 100%;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 2;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px grey;
}

li a {
 text-decoration-line: none;
 color: rgba(102,102,102,0.75);
}

ul {
 margin-right: 30px;
 margin-top: 25px;
}

li {
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 1.55rem;
 margin-right: 20px;
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
}

li a:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 color: #1a1a1a;
 transition: all 0.7s ease;
}

.after:after {
 position: relative;
 left: 12px;
 top: 2px;
 display: inline-block;
 content: "";
 width: 1px;
 height: 20px;
 background-color: rgba(102,102,102,0.25);
}

.logo {
 color: red;
 font-size: 3.7rem;
 margin: 10px;
 opacity: 1;
 margin-left: 30px;
}

/*---MAIN---*/

.contact h2 {
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
 color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.85);
 font-size: 3rem;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.contact h2:after {
 content: '';
 width: 18px;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: red;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 13px;
}

.contact h2:before {
 content: '';
 width: 18px;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: red;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 13px;
}

.quote-info {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 width: 30%;
 margin: 20px;
 background-color: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.2);
 margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.quote-info input, .quote-info textarea {
 width: 85%;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-bottom: 17px;
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
 font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.quote-info p {
 color: rgb(102, 102, 102);
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 1.45rem;
 font-weight: bolder;
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
 margin-bottom: 0;
}

.quote-info .send-quote {
 width: 85%;
 background-color: red;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 color: white;
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
 border: none;
 outline: none;
 padding: 5px;
}

.send-quote:hover {
 transition: all 0.5s ease;
 background-color: #cc0000;
}

textarea {
 resize: none;
}

hr {
 width: 100%;
 color: rgba(102, 102, 102);
}

.contact .container {
 display: flex;
}

.contact-info h3 {
 color: rgb(102, 102, 102);
 font-size: 2.3rem;
 margin-left: 25px;
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
 margin-bottom: 0;
}

.contact-info h3:after {
 content: '';
 height: 1.5px;
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: grey;
 width: 340%;
 position: relative;
 top: -30px;
}

.contact-numbers div {
 margin-left: 30px;
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
 font-size: 1.35rem;
}

.contact-numbers i {
 color: red;
}

/*---FOOTER---*/

.footer .wrapper {
 display: flex;
}

.footer div {
 display: inline-block;
 flex-basis: 33.33%;
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
 color: rgba(102,102,102, 1);
 margin-top: 5px;
}

.footer h1 {
 font-size: 2rem;
 margin-top: 15px;
}

.footer .inner {
 margin-left: 55px;
}

.social .inner {
 margin-left: 45px;
}

.contact .inner {
 margin-left: 35px;
}

.footer .inner:before {
 display: inline-block;
 content: '';
 width: 27.1%;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.6);
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: 54px;
}


.links .inner:after {
 content: '';
 width: 10.5%;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: red;
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: -151px;
}

.social .inner:after {
 content: '';
 width: 5.8%;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: red;
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: -171px;
}

.contact .inner:after {
 content: '';
 width: 7.5%;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: red;
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: -174.5px;
}

.wrap:before {
 content: '';
 width: 100px;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: red;
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: 55px;
}

.links a {
 display: block;
 text-decoration-line: none;
 color: rgba(102,102,102, 1);
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 position: relative;
 top: -10px;
 transition: color 0.4s ease;
}

.links a:hover {
 color: red;
}

.contact p {
 position: relative;
 top: -10px;
}

.social i {
 font-size: 1.7rem;
 margin-right: 5px;
 position: relative;
 top: -20px;
 color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.7);
 transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.social i:hover {
 color: red;
 cursor: pointer;
}

#msg {
 margin-top: -15px;
}

.footer-textarea {
 background-color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.2);
 outline: none;
 color: rgba(102,102,102, 1);
 resize: none;
 width: 102%;
}

.footer button {
 position: absolute;
 margin-left: 23.2%;
 margin-top: -40px;
 border: none;
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 transition: all ease 0.4s;
 outline: none;
}

button:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 color: red;
}

.dark {
 color: red;
}

.copyright {
 position: absolute;
 background-color: white;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 padding-bottom: 4px;
}



/*------MEDIA-QUERIES------*/




@media screen and (max-width: 425px) {

 /*---NAV---*/

 .logo {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  margin-left: 10px;
 }

 ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }

 nav li {
  display: none;
 }

 .ham-menu {
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 4px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
 }

 .m1, .m2, .m3 {
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 4px;
  width: 35px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
 }

 /*---MAIN---*/

 header h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
 }

 .quote-info {
  width: 90%;
 }

 .quote-info p {
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
 }

 .contact .container {
  flex-direction: column;
 }

 .contact-info h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
 }

 .contact-info h3:after {
  width: 95%;
 }

 .contact-numbers {
  margin-top: -15px;
 }

 /*---FOOTER---*/

 .footer .wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
 }

 .footer div {
  margin: 0;
 }

 .footer h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-top: 10px;
 }

 .footer .inner {
  margin: 0;
 }

 .footer .inner:before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.6);
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 48px;
 }

 .links .inner:after {
  width: 33%;
  margin-top: -152px;
 }

 .social .inner {
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
 }

 .social .inner:after {
  content: '';
  width: 18%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: -40px;
 }

 .contact .inner:after {
  content: '';
  width: 24%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -148px;
 }

 .links a {
  margin-left: 5px;
 }

 .social h1 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
 }

 #msg {
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-right: 25.5%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 80px;
 }

 .footer button {
  right: 9.25%;
  margin-top: 0.2px;
 }

 .social i {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  margin-right: 2px;
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  left: 5px;
  color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.7);
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
 }

 .footer-textarea {
  width: 88.5%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
 }

 .contact p {
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
 }

 .copyright {
  background-color: red;
 }

 .copyright span {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
 }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
 .social .inner:after {
  margin-top: -36.5px;
  width: 20%;
 }

 .links .inner:after {
  width: 37%;
 }

 .contact .inner:after {
  width: 27%;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, intitial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Contact | Kane Concrete & Construction LLC</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/contact.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo|Bitter|Lato|Montserrat|Noto+Sans|Open+Sans|Poppins|Roboto|Sarabun|Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel|Asap|Krub|Oxygen|Rajdhani|Staatliches|Varela+Round" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <div class="contact-wrapper">
   <nav>
    <div class="logo">
     <i class="fab fa-accusoft"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="nav">
     <div class="ham-menu">
      <div class="m1"></div>
      <div class="m2"></div>
      <div class="m3"></div>
     </div>
     <ul>
      <li class="after"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li class="after"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li class="after"><a href="about.html#services">Services</a></li>
      <li class="after"><a href="careers.html">Careers</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </nav>

   <h1>Contact Us</h1>
  </div> 
 </header>

 <section class="contact">
  <h2>Get in touch</h2>

  <div class="container">
   <div class="quote-info">
    <p>Get a Quote</p>

    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Phone Number">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email">

    <textarea name="project-details" id="" cols="40" rows="7" placeholder="Give us the specifics on your project"></textarea>

    <button class="send-quote">Send</button>
   </div>

   <div class="contact-info">
    <h3>Contact info</h3>

    <div class="contact-numbers">
     <div>
      <i class="fas fa-phone"></i>
      <p>(208)546-7827 -Matt</p>
      <i class="fas fa-phone"></i>
      <p>(208)546-7827 -Keegan</p>
     </div>

     <div>
      <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
      <p>P.O. Box 50860 IF, ID 83405</p>
      <i class="fas fa-at"></i>
      <p>KaneConcrete@fake.com</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>

 <hr>
 
 <section class="footer">
  <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="links">
    <div class="inner">
     <h1>Quick Links</h1>

     <a href="#">Home</a>
     <a href="#">About</a>
     <a href="about.html#services">Services</a>
     <a href="careers.html">Careers</a>
     <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="social">
    <div class="inner">
     <h1>Social</h1>

     <i class="fab fa-linkedin"><a href="#" class="social-net"></a></i>
     <i class="fab fa-facebook"><a href="#" class="social-net"></a></i>
     <i class="fab fa-twitter-square"><a href="#" class="social-net"></a></i>

     <p id="msg">Send some feedback!</p>
     <button name="msg">Send</button>
     <textarea name="msg" class="footer-textarea" cols="45" rows="5" placeholder="type here..."></textarea>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="contact">
    <div class="inner" class="wrap">
     <h1>Contact</h1>

     <p>(208)546-7827 - <span class="dark">Matt</span></p>
     <p>(208)546-7827 - <span class="dark">Keegan</span></p>
     <p><span class="dark">Address</span> - P.O. Box 50860 IF, ID 83405</p>
     <p><span class="dark">Email</span> - KaneConcrete@fake.com</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="copyright"><span>&copy; 2019 - Kane Concrete & Construction | ALL RIGHTS RESERVED</span></div>
 </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I suggest you provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example for this question.

Comment: ok just added it. Can you help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce the problem here (or I didn't understand it completely). But let me point some possible problems with the CSS code there:

To create the red lines, you create an element *after* the content of the sections. To adjust the position, you are setting the margin to a negative value. This is problematic because the size of the section is not constant, so, the red line will have a sort of undefined position (actually it is bottom of section minus some pixels).

You can set the margin to 0 to verify how the size of the section is volatile (it will change when a line wraps, if the font changes, maybe from browser to browser, etc). I recommend instead using a natural flow, and add a line where its position is. A simple example could be:

```css
header {
  width: 300px;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.line {
  height: 2px;
  background: black;
}

.red-line {
  height: 2px;
  background: red;
  width: 30%;
  margin-top: -2px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Quick Links</h1>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="red-line"></div>
</header>
```

The negative margin here works because `.red-line` will always be 2px below `.line`.

Cya!